# KDE - Show alt-tab window on all monitors

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

How to enable showing the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> window (not sure how it is called, maybe task switcher?) on all monitors at a same time?

Comment: Have you looked at the options in `System Settings > Window Management > Task Switcher`?

Comment: Yes, but only thing which mentions screens is filtering of content (shown windows in the task switcher) which is not what I want. My reason why I want this functionality is that I have 2nd monitor mirrored to projector and using wireless keyboard to control my PC. But when I am watching a projector and focus is on the main monitor then I see nothing when I press alt-tab.My main monitor has vastly larger resolution so navigating mouse to the smaller monitor is usually quite a pain, because I have to blindly hit center of the border of that main monitor in order to get mouse to the other monitor